# Bid Rent Curves - Plotting Circles of Projected Radii from Another Dimension

Tags: r, plot, 3d

### The goal is to reproduce this [Bid-Rent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bid_rent_theory) graph in R:

[image: Bid Rent Graph]

**The challenge is to draw the projected circles. So far I got:**

[image: My 2D Plot]

The 2D part is created by the R code below with the traditional graphic system in base R:

```
#Distance
X <- seq(0,7,1)

#Bid Rent Curves: Commercial, Industrial, Residential 
com <- -5*X + 10
ind <- -2*X + 7  
res <- -0.75*X + 4

graph <- plot(X, com, type="l", col="green", ylim=c(0,10), xlab="", ylab="", axes=FALSE)
lines(X, ind, col="red")
lines(X, res, col="blue")
abline(v=0, h=0)

segments(1,0, 1,5, lty=2)
segments(2.5,0, 2.5,2, lty=2)

title(main="Bid Rent Curves", sub="Alonso Model", 
      xlab="Distance from CBD", ylab="Rent per m2")

text(2.5,7.5, "Commercial", col="green")
text(3.5,4, "Industrial", col="red")
text(5.5,2, "Residential", col="blue")
```

1. (Detail: Why the curves do not respect the ylim = 0 ?)
2. How make the projection and draw the semi-circles?

It is not exactly a 3D plot. I have looked into plot3D and rgl. I am not sure which packages or strategy to use from here.

Comment: The ylim question is easy. Look at '?par'. The default settings add extra space around max and min point values so that the "dots" can be fully represented. You can change to axis type/style: `yaxs="i"`. They do not look like circles or even chords in the picture you offered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm taking you at your word that you want circles, so you need to push the plot area into the upper right corner:

```
outHalfCirc <- function(r,colr) {opar=par(xpd=TRUE, new=TRUE) #plot ouside plot area
   polygon(x=seq(r,-r,by=-0.1), 
          y= -sqrt(r^2 - seq(r,-r,by=-0.1)^2) , # solve r^2 = x^2 +y^2 for y
           xlim =c(0,7 ), ylim=c(0,10), col=colr,  # need xlim and ylim to match base plot ranges
           yaxs="i", yaxt="n", xaxs="i") # yaxis off; x and y axes meet at origin
  par(opar)}
```

Then push plot up and to the right: This will draw a colored half-circles (largest first so they overlap) below the y=0 line.

```
png()  # send to image file;  not needed for testing
opar <- par(mar=c(15, 15, 2,2) ) # default units are in widths of text-"line".
# the margins start at lower, then clockwise

# run your code

outHalfCirc(5.5, "blue")
outHalfCirc(2.5, "red")
outHalfCirc(1, "green")
dev.off()  # complete image production
par(opar)  # different than the 'opar' inside the function
```

Voila! Although not really circles because the aspect ratio is not 1. That can be fixed (or you could set the xlim and ylim to be equal.
[image]